# How to join two entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, linq-to-objects

### How to join two entities

my entity name customer

```
Public Class Customer
{
   Name string {get;set;}
   Address string {get;set;}
}
```

### I got result

```
Customer customer = this.customerService.GetAll();
Customer person = this.supplierService.GetAll();
```

how to join two entities in  using linq
    output exepected for single entity

Comment: Provide more details please. Why does GetAll() return one `Customer`? Why do two services return the same entities? Do the services have their own contexts? What is the primary key? What do you mean by _output exepected for single entity_?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

As per the comment you want to join this in one entity called output , so you can do it with the help of anonymous type and join

```
 var data = from c in customer 
               join p in person 
               on p.ID equals c.ID
               select new 
                {
                       PersonName = p.Name,
                       CustomerName - c.Name
                       PersonAdd = p.Add
                       CustomerAdd = c.Add
                  };
```

---

join will work like this

Check for more detail : [**SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

```
var data = from c in customer 
           join p in person 
           on p.ID equals c.ID
           select c;
```

image presetnation 
[image]

or

[**Linq Join on Mutiple columns**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2011/10/linq-join-on-mutiple-columns-using.html)

```
var cust = from c in Customers
           join p in persons on
             new { Name= c.Name, Address= c.Address }    
           equals
             new { Name= p.Name, Address= p.Address }    
           select c;
```

Comment: Above code not working i getting Error : Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Entities.Customer'. 'Join' not found.

Comment: var customers = new Customer();   /// Customer is Entity
var persons = personservice.GetById(id); /// Return value Entity
customers = customerservice.GetAll(id); // Return value Entity

Comment: getting two entities result set for 1. customers, 2. Persons, need to join those two entities in single result set output

Answer (score 1):

For first

```
Customer customer = this.customerService.GetAll();
Customer person = this.supplierService.GetAll();
```

I thing `GetAll()` must return collection or enumerable of customers. Isn't it?
Then, i thing you need union instead join!